# Combining alert rules for all metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a `alert.rules.yml` file which looks like this

```
groups:
  - name: my-alert-rules
    rules:
      - alert: FileCountRANRRCTooHigh
        expr: ((file_count_RAN_RRC - file_count_RAN_RRC offset 24h) / (file_count_RAN_RRC offset 24h) * 100) > 80
        for: 30s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "File count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased significantly"
          description: "The file count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased by over 80% in the last 24 hours."

      - alert: FileCountGiTooHigh
        expr: ((file_count_Gi - file_count_Gi offset 24h) / (file_count_Gi offset 24h) * 100) > 80
        for: 30s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "File count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased significantly"
          description: "The file count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased by over 80% in the last 24 hours."

      - alert: FileCountGnTooHigh
        expr: ((file_count_Gn - file_count_Gn offset 24h) / (file_count_Gn offset 24h) * 100) > 80
        for: 30s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "File count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased significantly"
          description: "The file count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased by over 80% in the last 24 hours."

      - alert: FileCountRANVSETooHigh
        expr: ((file_count_RAN_VSE - file_count_RAN_VSE offset 24h) / (file_count_RAN_VSE offset 24h) * 100) > 80
        for: 30s
        labels:
          severity: warning
        annotations:
          summary: "File count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased significantly"
          description: "The file count for {{ $labels.folder }} increased by over 80% in the last 24 hours."
```

I am wondering if there's a better way to write this since the expression for all rules is similar

```
((file_count_{{ $labels.folder }} - file_count_{{ $labels.folder }} offset 24h) / (file_count_{{ $labels.folder }} offset 24h) * 100) > 80
```

and have only one block under rules

Comment: First of all, root of your problem is that didn't follow recommendations on metric naming. [They should never be procedurally generated](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#naming). If you would expose them properly with the same name and folder as a label, this wouldn't be a problem now.

Comment: Based on your rules and previous question, I assume that all those metrics additionally have a label `folder` with unique per metric value. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for the input regarding metric naming. Yes, my metrics have label `folder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prometheus name of metric in selector can be address in two ways: either in form `name{}` or through built-in label `__name__`.

So selector `{name =~ "file_count_.+"}` will get you all metrics with name starting with `file_count_`.

Since you report that your metrics have additional labels `folder` you can simply use expression `({name =~ "file_count_.+"} - {name =~ "file_count_.+"} offset 24h) / ({name =~ "file_count_.+"} offset 24h) * 100 > 80` in a single rule, and it will address all the metrics with the name starting with `file_count_` at the same time.

---

Additionally, I'd like to repeat here, that root of your problem is that you didn't follow recommendations on metric naming. [They should never be procedurally generated](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#naming). If you would expose them properly with the same name and folder as a label, query for this kind of rule will be straightforward, and wouldn't require duplication of the exposition side.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This works, however I'll follow your recommendation to rewrite my metrics.